# REST API - how to write new options for a custom field with select type?

Tags: api, custom-fields

Using the contact - getoptions method you can read the list of options for a custom field with select type.

> /civicrm/civicrm/extern/rest.php?entity=Contact&action=getoptions&api_key=userkey&key=sitekey&json={"sequential":1,"field":"custom_5"}

But how can I create new options using the API?

Comment: Oh, I think it's OptionValue. Let me check ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CustomField - get method to get data for the select custom field who's options you want to edit. Note down the "option_group_id" value.

Then use the OptionGroup and OptionValue API methods with the Option Group you just noted. With this you can add new options.

Comment: You can also use a chained API to do this in one call if necessary!  In Civi 4.7, I believe you can also use a joined API call here as well.

Answer (score 0):

As james mentioned, it's entity=optionvalue and action=create

However, as opposed as what you shared for the getoption, it isn't possible to have the values you want to create as a get parameter, they have to be in post (for security reasons).

So the easiest is to use post for everything, it works and avoid the issue of knowing if it's a destructive operation or not that you want to perform in the api.

and depending of the language you use, we might already have a wrapper that hide all these details and take care of calling the right url with the right params